# onDraw() method not drawing all of the bitmaps

Tags: android, view, bitmap, ondraw

I have an app that draws planets and the horoscope according to the person's birthday.  I use the `onDraw()` method in a custom `View` which is added to a `FrameLayout` in `XML`.  The issue is that when I leave the page and put adjust the date, the activity only draws the planets but not the zodiac signs for the new date.  All of those "re"-drawings take place in the same `onDraw()` method and I can see that the `onDraw()` method gets called even the part that adds the zodiac sign bitmaps.  Given that they are being called I can't tell what is going wrong and feel like it has something to do with bitmaps.  And since the planets are redrawn I'm even more confused about what the issue could be.  I have included the code that is supposedly being executed but not showing up on the screen.

```
    Log.i("ascendet planets", Integer.toString(ascendent));

    Bitmap capricornBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.capricorn);
    Bitmap aquariusBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aquarius);
    Bitmap piscesBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pisces);
    Bitmap airesBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aires);
    Bitmap taurusBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.taurus);
    Bitmap geminiBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gemini);
    Bitmap cancerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cancer);
    Bitmap leoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.leo);
    Bitmap virgoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.virgo);
    Bitmap libraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.libra);
    Bitmap scorpioBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorpio);
    Bitmap sagitariusBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sagittarius);


    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<>();
    bitmapArray.add(capricornBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(aquariusBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(piscesBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(airesBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(taurusBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(geminiBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(cancerBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(leoBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(virgoBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(libraBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(scorpioBitmap);
    bitmapArray.add(sagitariusBitmap);




    int bitmapWidth;
    int bitmapHeight;



    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    for (int i = ascendent; i < ascendent + 12; i++) {
        int multiplier = i - ascendent;
        bitmapWidth = bitmapArray.get(i%12).getWidth();
        bitmapHeight = bitmapArray.get(i%12).getHeight();

        x = (float) getPositionX(r_adjusted, marginOneSide, multiplier * 30 + 15, ascendent);
        y = (float) getPositionY(r_adjusted, height, multiplier * 30 +  15,          ascendent);

        x += bitmapWidth / 2;
        y -= bitmapHeight / 2;

        Log.i("bitmapWidth", Integer.toString(bitmapHeight));
        Log.i("bitmapHeight", Integer.toString(bitmapHeight));
        Log.i("i in planets", Integer.toString(i));

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapArray.get(i % 12), x, y, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to log the "x" and "y"? Are the values correct after all the calculations?

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  The functions getPostionX() and getPositionY() simply return the values of X and Y on a circle at 15, 45, 75... 345 degrees.  Those points then receive the zodiac sign bitmaps.  The zodiac bitmaps are loaded the first time on the screen, but they only are loaded once.  The zodiac signs are supposed to change positions with the time.  If a different time and date are put in the planets do change positions, but not the zodiac symbols despite going through the same onDraw() method.  I'll post the x, y coordinates though now.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  A simple answer.  I logged x and y I realized I had a (+ n*Math.PI/6) that I hadn't put inside Math.toRadians() inside a cosine function.   So problem solved.  Thanks for the outside perspective. Probably shaved a day of hair tearing out.